# Cannot resolve method Color.valueOf(int)

Tags: java, android, colors

I want to create Color objects from Strings like `"#b66c61"` and`"#33b7c4"`.

This is my code:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
......
 String color_string = "#b66c61";
 int color_int = Integer.parseInt(color_string.substring(1, color_string.length()-1));
 Color color = Color.valueOf(color_int);
```

when I run it, I get the errer: `Cannot resolve method valueOf(int)`
although I'm sure the method exists : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

any help?

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color)

Comment: Color.valueOf() is taking a hexadecimal string as a parameter and you are passing integer values which are not possible.

Comment: @SarthakMittal I don't want to put themin my ressources, the color changes dynamically, that was just an example

Comment: @Chetanchadha  Color.valueOf() takes a colorint as indicated in the docs

Comment: @M.Dhaouadi you substring `"#b66c61"` to get `"b66c61"`, which doesn't make sense using parseInt. Use `Color.valueOf(Color.parseColor(color_string))`

Comment: @M.Dhaouadi Also, the `valueOf` functions are only available in API26+ what version are you using?

Comment: i'm using 25, that's propbably the issue ,thks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use `parseColor`. see below -

```
String color_string = "#b66c61";
int myColor = Color.parseColor(color_string)
// use int color to set Color
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

The method `valueOf` has been introduced in Android from API 26 onwards only. So it won't be available in other APIs and also there is no support library out there yet for 26. Thee exact use of this method would be illustrated only when things get out more clearly after the launch.

[Check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: this is wrong, this gives error: required android.graphics.Color, found int

Comment: Oh yes, sorry wrong typecast. So you can use int color directly to set it in any of your views.

Comment: @M.Dhaouadi check my updated answer

Comment: still not an answer, I want to create a Color instance

Comment: Why do you need a color instance. There is no need in Android for that as all layouts only accept the int color?

Comment: @kapsym you are right

Comment: @kapsym  because I need to save the color in DB, so there is no way todo it with code ?

Comment: I am saying so far there is no use of it. Even if you get a color instance you wont be able to use it anywhere as all methods would take only int. From Android O onwards the valueOf method has been added to Color to get the Color value in a defined Color space but the total use of it is still not clear.

Comment: And if you need to save it in DB, save the hex value and get it and convert everytime you want to use it. Or save int value. @M.Dhaouadi

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

like this

```
String color_string = "#b66c61";
int color = Color.parseColor(color_string);
```

From Android documentation:

**Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'**

Comment: this is wrong, this gives error: required android.graphics.Color, found int

Comment: @M.Dhaouadi check updated ans

Comment: still not an answer, I want a Color instance, not an int. and `Color mycolor = Color.valueOf(color);` gives `Cannot resolve Method` error